# iOS Simulator doesn't show the correct scene until after two touches

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game with a main menu, but when I run the game in iOS Simulator it doesn't show the scene correctly, like shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Main menu scene]

However, when I move to the option menu scene and return to the main menu scene it shows the scene in the correct way.

[image: Option menu scene]

[image: Main menu scene with correct display]

**This is the code for the main menu:**

```
let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayButton")
let optionButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Options")
let facebookButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Facebook")
let twitterButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Twitter")
let gamecenterButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Gamecenter")
let nosoundButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Nosound")

let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bar")
let character = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Character")
let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
let mountains = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Mountains")
let water = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Water")
let sand = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sand")
let sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
let cloud01 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud01")
let cloud02 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud02")
let cloud03 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud03")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    addScene()
    addMenuButtons()
    addSocial()

}

func addScene() {

    self.backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.backgroundImage.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.backgroundImage.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.backgroundImage.zPosition = 1

    self.mountains.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.mountains.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.mountains.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.mountains.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.mountains.zPosition = 2

    self.water.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.water.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.water.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.water.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.water.zPosition = 3

    self.sand.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.sand.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
    self.sand.size.width = self.frame.size.width
    self.sand.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    self.sand.zPosition = 4

    self.sun.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.sun.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
    self.sun.size.width = 150
    self.sun.size.height = 150
    self.sun.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud01.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud01.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud01.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud01.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 50)
    self.cloud01.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud02.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud02.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud02.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud02.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 200)
    self.cloud02.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud03.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud03.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud03.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud03.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 125)
    self.cloud03.zPosition = 2

    self.addChild(self.backgroundImage)
    self.addChild(self.mountains)
    self.addChild(self.water)
    self.addChild(self.sand)
    self.addChild(self.sun)
    self.addChild(self.cloud01)
    self.addChild(self.cloud02)
    self.addChild(self.cloud03)
}

func addMenuButtons() {
    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * (3/5))
    self.playButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.playButton.size.height = self.playButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.playButton.zPosition = 5

    self.optionButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.playButton.position.y - self.playButton.size.height - 10)
    self.optionButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.optionButton.size.height = self.optionButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.optionButton.zPosition = 5

    self.nosoundButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    self.nosoundButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 10, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 10)
    self.nosoundButton.size.height = 40
    self.nosoundButton.size.width = 40
    self.nosoundButton.zPosition = 5

    // Add buttons
    self.addChild(self.playButton)
    self.addChild(self.optionButton)
    self.addChild(self.nosoundButton)
}

func addSocial() {

    self.twitterButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.twitterButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 10, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 10)
    self.twitterButton.size.height = 40
    self.twitterButton.size.width = 40
    self.twitterButton.zPosition = 5

    self.facebookButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.facebookButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 10, self.twitterButton.position.y + self.twitterButton.size.height + 5)
    self.facebookButton.size.height = 40
    self.facebookButton.size.width = 40
    self.facebookButton.zPosition = 5

    self.gamecenterButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    self.gamecenterButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 10, self.nosoundButton.position.y + self.nosoundButton.size.height + 5)
    self.gamecenterButton.size.height = 40
    self.gamecenterButton.size.width = 40
    self.gamecenterButton.zPosition = 5

    self.addChild(self.twitterButton)
    self.addChild(self.facebookButton)
    self.addChild(self.gamecenterButton)
}
```

**This is the option menu code:**

```
let removeAdsButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Removeads")
let resetHighScoreButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Resethighscore")
let creditsButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Credits")
let backButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BackButton")
let facebookButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Facebook")
let twitterButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Twitter")
let gamecenterButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Gamecenter")
let nosoundButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Nosound")

let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bar")

let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
let mountains = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Mountains")
let water = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Water")
let sand = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sand")
let sun = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sun")
let cloud01 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud01")
let cloud02 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud02")
let cloud03 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Cloud03")

var score = 0

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    addScene()
    addMenuButtons()
    addSocial()

}

func addScene() {

    self.backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.backgroundImage.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.backgroundImage.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.backgroundImage.zPosition = 1

    self.mountains.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.mountains.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.mountains.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.mountains.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.mountains.zPosition = 2

    self.water.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.water.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.water.size.width = self.frame.size.width * 1.4
    self.water.size.height = self.frame.size.height * 1.4
    self.water.zPosition = 3

    self.sand.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.sand.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))
    self.sand.size.width = self.frame.size.width
    self.sand.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    self.sand.zPosition = 4

    self.sun.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.sun.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
    self.sun.size.width = 150
    self.sun.size.height = 150
    self.sun.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud01.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud01.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud01.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud01.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 50)
    self.cloud01.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud02.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud02.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud02.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud02.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 200)
    self.cloud02.zPosition = 2

    self.cloud03.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    self.cloud03.size.width = self.frame.size.width / 3
    self.cloud03.size.height = self.cloud01.size.width / 5
    self.cloud03.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 50, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 125)
    self.cloud03.zPosition = 2

    self.addChild(self.backgroundImage)
    self.addChild(self.mountains)
    self.addChild(self.water)
    self.addChild(self.sand)
    self.addChild(self.sun)
    self.addChild(self.cloud01)
    self.addChild(self.cloud02)
    self.addChild(self.cloud03)
}

func addMenuButtons() {

    self.removeAdsButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - self.removeAdsButton.size.height * (2/3))
    self.removeAdsButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.removeAdsButton.size.height = self.removeAdsButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.removeAdsButton.zPosition = 5

    self.resetHighScoreButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.removeAdsButton.position.y - self.removeAdsButton.size.height - 5)
    self.resetHighScoreButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.resetHighScoreButton.size.height = self.resetHighScoreButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.resetHighScoreButton.zPosition = 5

    self.creditsButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.resetHighScoreButton.position.y - self.resetHighScoreButton.size.height - 5)
    self.creditsButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.creditsButton.size.height = self.creditsButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.creditsButton.zPosition = 5

    self.backButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.creditsButton.position.y - self.creditsButton.size.height - 5)
    self.backButton.size.width = self.frame.size.width * (36/100)
    self.backButton.size.height = self.backButton.size.width * (18/100)
    self.backButton.zPosition = 5

    self.nosoundButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    self.nosoundButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 10, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 10)
    self.nosoundButton.size.height = 40
    self.nosoundButton.size.width = 40
    self.nosoundButton.zPosition = 5

    // Add buttons
    self.addChild(self.removeAdsButton)
    self.addChild(self.resetHighScoreButton)
    self.addChild(self.creditsButton)
    self.addChild(self.backButton)
    self.addChild(self.nosoundButton)

}

func addSocial() {

    self.twitterButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.twitterButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 10, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + 10)
    self.twitterButton.size.height = 40
    self.twitterButton.size.width = 40
    self.twitterButton.zPosition = 5

    self.facebookButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    self.facebookButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + 10, self.twitterButton.position.y + self.twitterButton.size.height + 5)
    self.facebookButton.size.height = 40
    self.facebookButton.size.width = 40
    self.facebookButton.zPosition = 5

    self.gamecenterButton.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0)
    self.gamecenterButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 10, self.nosoundButton.position.y + self.nosoundButton.size.height + 5)
    self.gamecenterButton.size.height = 40
    self.gamecenterButton.size.width = 40
    self.gamecenterButton.zPosition = 5

    self.addChild(self.twitterButton)
    self.addChild(self.facebookButton)
    self.addChild(self.gamecenterButton)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)` with `0` and `CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)` with `self.frame.size.width` same for the y positions.

Comment: Doesn't work. The odd thing is that when I check the position it shows the correct position.

Comment: The problem as I can see here only for those object that doesn't have default anchor points (0.5,0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I've added `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` to the view. This fixed the issue.